# How do I implement OAuth with Discord using flask dance?

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, discord, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-dance

I used the same code for google oauth and I used flask-dance. This worked with google, but didn't work with discord. I get an error message saying that I need to be logged in to reach the home page, meaning that the discord account hasn't been registered in the sqlite database.

Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, Blueprint
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, login_required
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
from flask_dance.contrib.discord import make_discord_blueprint, discord
from flask_dance.consumer import oauth_authorized, oauth_error
from flask_dance.consumer.storage.sqla import SQLAlchemyStorage
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
from __init__ import db
from models import User, OAuth


discord_blueprint = make_discord_blueprint(client_id= "1001891783061553233", client_secret="QMvsUwbFGCLgYWgr8GAQ5ae2WibPTeDB", scope=["identify", "email"])


discord_bp = make_discord_blueprint(storage = SQLAlchemyStorage(OAuth, db.session, user = current_user))

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(discord_blueprint)
def discord_logged_in(blueprint, token):
if not token:
    flash("Failed to log in", category="error")
    return
resp = blueprint.session.get("/users/@me")
if not resp:
    msg = "Failed to fetch user info"
    flash(msg, category="error")
    return
discord_name = resp.json()["name"]
discord_user_id = resp.json() ["id"]

query = OAuth.query.filter_by(
    provider = blueprint.name, provider_user_id = discord_user_id
)

try:
    oauth = query.one()
except(NoResultFound):
    discord_user_login = discord_name

    oauth = OAuth(provider = blueprint.name,
        provider_user_id = discord_user_id,
        provider_user_login = discord_user_login,
        token=token,
        )
if current_user.is_anonymous:
    if oauth.user:
        login_user(oauth.user)
    else:
        user = User(username = discord_name)

        oauth.user = user
        db.session.add_all([user, oauth])
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(user)

else:
    if oauth.user:
        if current_user != oauth.user:
            url = url_for("auth.merge", username = oauth.user.username)
            return redirect(url)
    else:
        oauth.user = current_user
        db.session.add(oauth)
        db.commit()


return redirect(url_for("main.profile"))
```

The google code is the same as the discord one and my redirect uri is localhost:5000/login/"oauthprovider"/authorized. For some reason the discord user isnt registered in the database?

Comment: I too would like to know. Whatever I use, i get an invalid redirect error.

The "redirect_to and redirect_url" args also don't seem to do anything for me, as the redirect url always seems to be /discord/discord :-/

Answer (score 1):

I took me many hours to figure it out because there's literally 0 guides for this, but this the approach that worked for me in the end. This is an extract from my source, so you can see the [full implementation here](https://github.com/db0/KoboldAI-Horde). I'm still working out some kinks like trying to be able to turn off `os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT']` but I can login at least.

```py
@REST_API.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    discord_data = None
    if discord.authorized:
        discord_info_endpoint = '/api/users/@me'
        try:
            discord_data = discord.get(discord_info_endpoint).json()
        except oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.TokenExpiredError:
            pass

@REST_API.route('/discord')
def discord_login():
    return redirect(url_for('discord.login'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    discord_client_id = os.getenv("DISCORD_CLIENT_ID")
    discord_client_secret = os.getenv("DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET")
    REST_API.secret_key = os.getenv("secret_key")
    discord_blueprint = make_discord_blueprint(
        client_id = discord_client_id,
        client_secret = discord_client_secret,
        scope = ["identify"],
    )
    REST_API.register_blueprint(discord_blueprint,url_prefix="/discord")
```